# Python Performance concern - Multiple methods reading same Pandas Data Frame from a particular Pickle file

Tags: python, pandas, pickle

We have multiple (4) methods reading the same Pandas Data Frame from a particular / the same - Pickle file stored on the local directory. 
Code creating the only pickle file as below :-

```
df_for_bokeh = pd.read_sql(sql_command,engine)
df_for_bokeh.to_pickle("./df_holoviewPlots.pkl")
```

Code snippets from the methods reading the pickle file as below :-

```
df_for_bokeh = pd.read_pickle("./df_holoviewPlots.pkl")
df_for_bokeh1 = pd.read_pickle("./df_holoviewPlots.pkl")
df_for_bokeh2 = pd.read_pickle("./df_holoviewPlots.pkl")
df_for_bokeh3 = pd.read_pickle("./df_holoviewPlots.pkl")
```

As seen above 
My concern with performance is - would this be better or should we pickle the DF into 4 separate in place of the same Pickle file.

We can not have the pickle file - unpickled to give only 1 DataFrame . We shall need atleast - 4 different data frames to be read from the one Pickle file , and that too almost at the same time.

Comment: Why don't you just load it once and make as many copies as you need?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga - Hey Juan - we probably dont want to do that - as our initial reason for pickeling was to get a smaller set from PSQL and not keep it within the memory and make it persist on the local directory . Making copies would again probably be a memory intensive task . Would you still suggest making copies - we could try that and maybe time it , for performance. Our data frames could be fairly large in size and we would not know how many users might create these 4-5 consecutive / concurrent data frames.

Comment: you end up with the same number of data-frames, do you think reading it from a pickle file would save memory?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga - Hey Juan - 1/ We read a fairly large DF from PSQL , 2/ We pickle this DF to a local dir and not keep it available in memory , 3/ When required we read back the Pickle file and get back our pandas DF . All of this is pretty standard and done so as to memory usage is saved - as if were not to write the DF to local DIR as a Pickle , the DF would have some / a large amount of memory - allocated to hold it ?

Comment: Why is that relevent? currently, you read a pickle file 4 different times creating 4 different data-frames. this is equivalent to reading the pickle file 1 time then make 3 more copies from that first dataframe. in both cases, you end up with 4 identical copies of a dataframe, requiring the same amount of memory in each case.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga - Hey Juan - Ok seems fair enough - let me try that tomorrow and get back to you - thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you can't do the following:

1. Set a loading lock state
2. Load the date once
3. Deep copy to as many objects as you need
   https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/copy.html
4. Release the loading lock state

This would give you the same data in 4 different independent data frames.

Comment: Hey Mike - thanks for your answer / suggestion - let me try this and see how this works - i should be able to try this out at work tomorrow morning thanks

Comment: Sure.  The lock state idea is only if you need to wait while this operation is completed for whatever reason.  Otherwise, I think just the deep copy should work.